# How to specify mutable pending intent in Android 12?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-pendingintent, android-12

I am aware there's tons of similar questions, but I cannot find anything that answers this one particular one.

I am trying to update my app to use a mutable `PendingIntent`. I know that for Android 12+, I can do

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, updateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
```

However, my app has a `minSdk` of 24 and `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` was added in sdk 31. When I try this

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, updateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
} else {
   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, updateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

I get a warning in the `else` block in Android Studio for "Missing Pending Intent Mutability Flag". Is this an Android Studio bug? Or do I need to do something else to handle mutable pending intents?

Comment: Ever manage to find a way to fix this? I have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `if` block. You can just use:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                updateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT |
                              PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
```

even though the constant `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` was introduced in API 31, this code will work on older versions of Android as this flag will just be ignored by versions of Android older than API 31.

Comment: When I do this, Android Studio gives me a red line saying "Field requires API level S (current min is 24)". Hitting opt+return gives me the suggestion to add the if block.

Comment: Try adding @SuppressLint on a line before that line. In this case there's no problem on lower API levels, that flag will just be ignored.

Comment: Are you aware of any documentation guaranteeing that this will be okay on lower api levels?

Comment: You can look at the documentation for the flags. This flag has a specific value that was not used in previous API levels. I can't guarantee anything, and if you are truly paranoid you can use your `if` statement to make sure it isn't used on older API levels, but I don't see any reason why that would be necessary.